# Joining lists in Python 3 like SQL JOIN

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, join

I have 2 objects (imagine them as database tables):

O1:
field1(id)
field2
field3

O2:
field1
field2
field3(id)
field4

I have 2 lists:
L1 is a list of O1 objects
L2 is a list of O2 objects

**Question:** is there a way to join these two lists by L1.field1 and L2.field3 just like an SQL JOIN? The item count of the two lists are always equal (1:1 relation) but they are not necessarily sorted by these two fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the simple and naive way:

```
joined = [ i + j for i in L1 for j in L2 if i[0] == j[2] ]
```

It will certainly be much more efficient than pandas for tiny lists, but will perform poorly for large ones.

A mid way would be to use an auxiliary dictionnary:

```
D2 = { j[2]: j for j in L2 }
joined = [ i + D2[i[0]] for i in L1 ]
```

It will perform now on O(len(L1)) + O(len(L2)) instead of O(len(L1)) * O(len(L2)). Still less efficient that the highly optimized pandas module for very large data sets, but far better that the naive approach for not too small lists.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` has a lot of functions to deal with data in this way.

Turn your lists into [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)s and then you can use [`pd.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join). Like SQL `JOIN` this lets you specify parameters like inner, left, right, outer.

```
dfL1.set_index(field1).join(dfL2.set_index(field3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I try do show an example, if I get the point. Let's say you have these classes:

```
class User():
  def __init__(self, id, name):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name

class Image():
  def __init__(self, id, user_id, filename):
    self.id = id
    self.user_id = user_id
    self.filename = filename
```

And the following collections:

```
users = [User(1, 'Jim'), User(2, 'Spock')]
images = [Image(1, 1, 'jim_1.jpg'), Image(2, 1, 'jim_2.jpg'), Image(3, 2, 'spk_1.jpg')]
```

Once you fetch a user form the collection, let's say the first:

```
user = users[0]
```

You can query for images in this way:

```
user_images = [ image for image in images if image.user_id == user.id ]

for image in user_images:
  print(image.filename)
```

While if you have the image, since in this case is a relation one to many:

```
image = images[0]
user = [user for user in users if user.id == image.user_id][0] # [0] as it is 1:n relation
```

---

**For the join table:**

```
join_table = [ {'name': user.name, 'filename': image.filename} for user in users for image in images if user.id == image.user_id ]

for e in join_table:
  print(e['name'], e['filename'])
```

Which returns:

```
# Jim jim_1.jpg
# Jim jim_2.jpg
# Spock spk_1.jpg
```